# How to override default "logfile" in python cli module?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I'm trying to use:

http://packages.python.org/pyCLI/#cli-log-logging-applications

specifically the `cli.log.LoggingApp` which automatically gives you the `-l --logfile` option. What is the best way to override the default `logfile` attribute? If no `-l` is provided, it defaults to `None` and output goes to `stdout`.

I would like to default this to a hard-coded local filename.

UPDATE:
I want to set the logfile location based on the value of an optional --dir=rundir argument. I think this is more involved since you need to parse the argument to know the value of "dir" which you want to use to make the name of the log file. I think the best work around would be to run the initial prerun and setup scripts 'manually' and manipulate the logger setup myself.

Comment: Just had a thought ... Maybe the solution is to have a cli.app.CommandLineApp that parses args and then pass this to one of the logging apps. If anyone knows of a forum where my posts would be more appropriate, please point me there. I am quite interested in this module.

Answer (score 1):

You can default this file name by supplying a `logfile` kwarg to the decorator:

```
import cli.log


@cli.log.LoggingApp(logfile='default.log')
def foo(app):
    print "I'm in the app!"
    app.log.error("Things are seriously wrong!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo.run()
```

The only issue (I could see, at least) in doing this, is that the help generated is wrong.  It still states the default is `stdout` (as of version 2.0.2, that is).  It looks like the help-text is hard-coded in the `LoggingMixin` class.

Comment: Thanks. That's probably the best to work with though it will be difficult to do what I actually want ... I realize I wasn't clear in the original post. What I was trying to do was make the logfile run in a default location as indicated an optional argument i.e. --dir=rundir. It's sort of in the blindspot of the cli app since "dir" will only be available after the argparser has run and I think you need to set the logfile name before the logger is setup. I'll try to update my OP.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't completely work either: Define the logging app inside the commandline app and specify the logfile there.

Problem is you don't get the verbose/quiet stuff pushed through.

```
@cli.app.CommandLineApp(description=globals()["__doc__"])
def main(app):
    logfile = app.params.logfile
    if logfile is None:
        logfile = "mylog.log"
    @cli.log.LoggingApp(description=globals()["__doc__"], logfile=logfile)
    def main_with_log(app):
        print("Printing log output to <%s>." % app.params.logfile
main.add_param("-d", "--dir", dest="dirname", default="./", help = "no help")
main.add_param("-l", "--logfile", default=None, help="log to file.")
```